# Does a system of linear equations with solutions modulo all primes have an integer solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Suppose we are given a finite system of linear equations $a_{i1} x_1 + \cdots + a_{in} x_n = b_i$ in the variables $x_i$, where the constants $a_{ij}$ and $b_i$ are all integers, and moreover suppose that the system of equations has a solution when viewed in $\mathbb Z/ p$ for every prime $p$ and also has a solution over $\mathbb Q$. Does it follow that the system of equations has a solution over $\mathbb Z$?

If we knew that the system had a solution over $\mathbb Z/ n$ for every integer $n$, then using the Chinese Remainder Theorem one can deduce that there is a solution over $\mathbb Z$. However, in this setting I don't see how to lift solutions modulo primes to a solution over the integers. I tried searching for a counterexample, but also found nothing.

Comment: $4x + 4y = 2 \hspace{15mm} $

Comment: @WillJagy, Can I encourage you to write that as an answer, so we can upvote it?  This platform discourages writing an answer in the comments.  I think it could be as simple as writing "No: consider $4x+4y=2$.".

Answer (score 0):

How about $$  4x + 4y = 2 $$
For any odd prime $p$,  we know $2,4$ are invertible $\pmod p.$ That leads to $x+y = \frac{1}{2}  \pmod p \; . \; $

I could have just written $4x = 2.$ Still possible $\pmod 2$ but impossible $\pmod 4$